# importing zbar object to page causes ERROR Error: "[object Object]"

Tags: cordova-plugins, ionic4, zbar

I need to implement a feature that is able to read QR-Code, and i've chosen the ZBar plugin to do so. I've already tested this plugin on a separate test app, and it worked just fine.

However, when i try to navigate to the page he plugin is imported, the app just throws the good old `ERROR Error: "[object Object]"` (seriously whats is that even supposed to mean).

I've figured out that the error is caused because of the import in the constructor (as suggested by the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/zbar)): `constructor(private zbar: ZBar) { }`

Any ideas on why this happens, or how to solve it?

Edit:
dependencies from my `package.json` file (@angular and @ionic depdendencies are supressed) for the plugins i'm using.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.10.0",
    "br-mask": "0.0.6",
    "cordova-android": "8.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-cszbar": "1.3.4",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.12.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-cszbar": {}
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you also tried the other qr code plugin in this app?

Because they conflict with each other. I was working on a test app experimenting with everything and when I added zbar I had lots of trouble getting it to work.

It turned out they were both trying to include stuff at the same time which conflicted.

Removing all traces of the original plugin fixed it for me.

If not then I would take a look at what other plugins you're using on that page - share some code!

Comment: no, im not trying to use any other plugin to scan qr-code, and on that page i'm using that plugin alone.

Comment: hmm was a long shot but thought I'd suggest it. If that doesn't work out then there is also [qr-scanner](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/qr-scanner) which is the one I ended up choosing for my project, although I can't recall why. Perhaps just that I like the ui better.

Comment: actually the one i used was [barcode-scanner](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner)

Comment: well, guess it'll have to do. Thanks for the recommendation!